# HAML Ruby - conditionals

Tags: ruby, haml, erb

I'm going through examples from 'Agile Web Dev with Rails' book, but mixing it with extra techniques i found useful - like haml.
Got one tricky issue, how to write down this erb partial:

```
<% if line_item == @current_item %>
<tr id="current_item">
<% else %>
<tr>
<% end %>
  <td><%= line_item.quantity %>&times;</td>
  <td><%= line_item.product.title %></td>
  <td class="item_price"><%= number_to_currency(line_item.total_price) %></td>
</tr>
```

In haml?

Tried sth like this:

```
-if line_item==@current_item
 %tr#current_item
-else
 %tr
%td!=line_item.quantity.to_s+"&times;"
%td=line_item.product.title
%td.item_price=number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```

But it prints out an empty TR without TD within...

Comment: When the indentation drops back a level, the TR tag will be closed.

Comment: That's right, but I have to drop back one level of indentation to end the if statement...

Comment: Correct, as written, you would; while Dylan's answer is correct, IMO this probably belongs in a partial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than having two separate `%tr` entries (in which case you would need to list your 3 td's under each tr, I think), you could just set the id in a conditional:

```
%tr{:id => (line_item == @current_item) ? "current_item" : false}
  %td!=line_item.quantity.to_s+"&times;"
  %td=line_item.product.title
  %td.item_price=number_to_currency(line_item.total_price)
```

Comment: If a value in a Haml attributes hash is false, the attribute is omitted altogether, so you could do `(line_item == @current_item) ? "current_item" : false` which would be closer to the original erb.